# Does Darkmoon Faire's specifics items disappear after the event?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm currently making a stock of Darkmoon Firewater using the new Darkmoon Fair currency introduced in 6.2 patch, which is Darkmoon Daggermaw.

Will these potions disappear from my inventory/bank after Darkmoon Fair has ended ?

And in a more general way, how can I know if a specific item is linked to a temporary event and will eventually disappear after that ?

Have checked on many sites like wowhead, wowdb .. but didn't found comments mentionning this probable issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, The items will stay in your inventory/bank so you can use them in the next darkmoon faire. I believe this happens for every event.

Source: Played since Cataclysm :D

Comment: but can I still use them between two darkmoon faire ? when there's no event at all ?

Comment: @Pronox Yes....

Comment: if there is a limit on use, it usually specifies any conditions in the item tooltip, checking on [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=78883/darkmoon-firewater) the tooltip does NOT say "Requires Darkmoon Faire". So yes, you will still be able to use them.

Comment: What sequoiad said ^^ :D